# React code keeps rerendering after changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this code keeps rerendering the page on every state change and when I add an image it keeps
rerendering infinitely without errors

```
const [adData, setAdData] = useState({
    name: "",
    link: "",
    fromDate: {},
    toDate: {},
    fromTime: {},
    toTime: {},
    iconEn: null,
    allViews: 0,
    userViews: 0,
  });
  const [iconEN, setIconEN] = useState(null);
  const [currentEnImg, setCurrentEnImg] = useState(null);
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setAdData({ ...adData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleOnCheck = (e) => {
    setAdData({ ...adData, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked});
  };
  if (iconEN) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      setCurrentEnImg(reader.result);
      setAdData({ ...adData, iconEn: iconEN });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(iconEN);
  }
```

what am I doing wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
if (iconEN) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      setCurrentEnImg(reader.result);
      setAdData({ ...adData, iconEn: iconEN });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(iconEN);
  }
```

every state set function re-render the application and on every re-render the same state set function is called that makes this process as a never ending loop.

**Solution:** try [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook with a proper `dependency` variable or `[]` and this problem will be solved.

In your case put your login inside useEffect like:

```
useEffect(() => {
     if (iconEN) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          setCurrentEnImg(reader.result);
          setAdData({ ...adData, iconEn: iconEN });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(iconEN);
      }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just add useEffects hook when page load

```
useEffect(()=>{
  /*
  Query logic
  */
  console.log('i fire once');},[]);
```

in this hook call your that function which call when entering the page
after use, this code does not render every time when change state
it might help